# Game server can connect on WiFi but not ethernet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

(My post on ServerFault was closed, I was told to post this here instead)

I am running a Paper Minecraft server on Ubuntu 20.04.

The server is running on a NUC over Ethernet and the WiFi is disabled.

All devices on the network are using the same (and the only) router, the default one that came with our ISP. It also acts as the access point.

Neither me nor my roommates can connect to it over Ethernet, but I am able to connect to the server over WiFi from my PC and laptop.

Know any thing that might cause this? Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I postulate a couple of possibilities -

1. Your devices are all on WIFI, and the router is set to do LAN ISOLATION - ie firewalling off WIFI from the LAN and is a fairly common security setting.
2. The Paper Minecraft server is binding on a specific IP/interface - the one associated with the WIFI connection.  (https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/2963730-failed-to-bind-to-port might be useful?)

Comment: I haven't been able to find the Isolation settings in the router. It's the default one from xfinity, so I'm not surprised at how bad the UI is.

Comment: I do not get an error message when starting the server, and I don't have port forwarding set up. Just over LAN. I tried it to see if it would fix the ethernet issue, but it didn't.

I've been messing with it and it can't resolve the host name when I enter 'ping www.google.com'. Then, I realized there's no DNS configured. I don't know how that relates to the server working on Wifi but not ethernet.

I should probably add that ssh works over WiFi, but not ethernet. 'ping <server ip>' works over both.